# Access nested class of template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, nested

```
template<class T>
class CData{
public:
    T::Buffer GetBuffer() = 0;
}

class CAudio : public CData<CAudio>{
public:
    struct Buffer{};
}
```

How can I implement a functionality like this?

This throws:
error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'BuffData'
error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
error C2039: 'BuffData': is not a member of 'CAudio'

Comment: `typename T::Buffer GetBuffer() = 0;`.

Comment: Missing `;` after class definition.

Comment: can you please post the real code and real error message? There is no `BuffData` in your code